# call template function with two template types determined at runtime C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have function below.

```
template<typename TypeBasedOnMonth, typename TypeBasedOnWeekday>
DoWork(){}
```

User provides input based on which `T1` and `T2` can be determined. I can have nested switch to have the `DoWork` invocation as below which I want to avoid.

```
switch (month)
{
case Month1:
  {
   switch (weekday)
   {
    case Weekday1:
        DoWork<TypeMonth1, TypeWeekday1>();
   }
   ...
case Month2:
   ...
  }
}
```

The above is leading to writing m*n invocation of DoWork ? Any better ways ?

Comment: Is this a solution looking for a problem? Can you not implement `DoWork` in terms of `month` and `weekday`?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". At least in this respect, C++ is a statically-typed language. Data types are bound to their objects at compile time, rather than at runtime, as you are attempting to do here.

Having said all that:

1) The given details are sparse, but it's quite possible that after reviewing what problem you are *really* trying to solve here, there's a different, cleaner solution. You just think that this is the answer to the original issue you are attempting to implement, and are trying to figure out how to implement it. A completely different approach to the given task at hand will probably result in a cleaner approach.

2) If all else fails, then it's time for an Automatic Spaghetti Code Generator[tm] to come to the rescue. Using a saved list of source enumerations, it shouldn't be difficult to write a quick little Perl script, or maybe an `XSLT` stylesheet, if working with `XML`-based data, to robo-generate canned skeleton code for the body of the switch, instead of doing it manually.

Some schools of thought might frown on this approach, but I just believe in using the right tool, for the right job. There are times when it makes sense to integrate an Automatic Spaghetti Code generator as part of the software build.

After all, what is `Lex`, or `Yacc`, if not an Automatic Spaghetti Code generator? Those very useful, and time-tested tools swallow a definition of a lexical tokenizer, or a language grammar, given in a specific, compact, precise form, and spit out a bunch of spaghetti code that implement a lexical analyzer, and a grammar parser.

If it's good for the goose, it's good for the gander, I say. If you can't come up with a different, cleaner solution for this, just write your own Automatic Spaghetti Code generator, for the task.

Comment: Yes, we can't skip having m*n (12*7) combinations. However what I am looking is replace nested switch (or nested if else's) by some other compact code approach e.g. have these combinations as keys in the map and have function as functor as value.

Comment: 12*7 isn't too big to implement a spaghetti code generator for. Whether the spaghetti code generator creates the body of a switch, or initialize a map of the kind you envision, that's a minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that a response may take on patterns of weekdays, or some patterns of months. This forms a 2d grid of 12 months by 7 days, and out of the 84 possibilities it is likely you intend many repeats.

What looks slightly better to me is a grid of function objects. Let's say out of the 84 possibilities, many are "DoNothing" days, whereas every Friday is "DoFriday", and something like "VacationMonday" is only done in summer months. With grid of function objects, empty cells would automatically be "DoNothing", whereas you could plug in function objects for certain combinations. A grid could be synthesized by a nested vector or array, perhaps:

```
 typedef std::array< std::array< std::shared_ptr< Worker >, 7 >, 12 > WorkGrid;
```

Each cell would either be empty, or fitted with a "virtual functor". A base, worker, would be something like:

```
struct Worker
{
 virtual void operator()(){};
};

struct VacationMonday : public Worker
{
 virtual void operator()() { ...do VacationMondayStuff...}
};
```

If there are more than a few different things to do, however, you may prefer a series of member functions, then use a pointer to member function (or maybe you prefer `std::function`) to call various member functions based on which is plugged into a cell.

```
template< typename O >
struct VWorker : public Worker
{
 O * Obj;
 void (O::*Func)();

 virtual void operator()() { (Obj->*Func)(); }

 VWorker( O *o, void ( O::*f )() ) : Obj( o ), Func( f ) {}
};
```

As an alternative to the grid concept, you could use a map where the two integers are keys, perhaps based on a std::tuple.

For this you would search the map for a matching tuple to find what functor to call. Consider these snippets:

```
typedef std::tuple< int, int >    Itpl;
typedef std::shared_ptr< Worker > WPtr;
typedef std::map< Itpl, WPtr >    WorkMap;
```

Defining the map and associated types. Then, assuming a class WorkObj with a collection of member functions to be called based on which Month/Day pair is to be searched, you'd declare the map with something like:

```
WorkMap wm;
```

Probably as a member of WorkObj, and subsequently populate the map in the constructor (or an initializer member function ) of WorkObj with something like:

```
wm[ Itpl( Month2, Weekday1 ) ] 
    = WPtr( new VWorker< WorkObj >( this, &WorkObj::MemFunc ) );
```

Note, my use of a virtual object base, Worker, with a derived template calling a member function via function pointer is an old fashioned approach now solved with std::function (and possibly uses of std::bind), so there are myriad ways of doing this, some dependent on what version of C++ you're supporting (especially pre or post C++11). Some of used boost for this support while waiting for C++11 support, some of us made our own (even earlier).

These are merely illustrations (no code was tested here) to suggest ways in which selecting a function (or, therefore, some act) based on data is often implemented. What you're inquiring about is more generalized in solutions for message maps in GUI applications, in order to interpret GUI messages, like mouse actions or button clicks, into function calls. The now outdated technique of creating a table of response functions with macros has been replaced in most GUI frameworks with a more dynamic database of function objects which usually resolve into calling member functions of classes representing Windows in a GUI.

Comment: yeah we can't skip having m*n (12*7) combinations. But we can compact the code by creating map having key as month and week values and value as function pointer or better written std::function. And invoke the function based on lookup from map single time.

Comment: std::map<std::pair<int month, int weekday>, std::function<void()>> doWorkMap = { {std::make_pair(month1, weekday1), DoWork<Month1Type, Weekday1Type>}, {std::make_pair(month1, weekday2), DoWork<Month1Type, Weekday2Type>}, ...}; doWorkMap[std::make_pair(monthvalue, weedayvalue)]();

Answer (score 0):

By introducing an intermediate single-parameter function template, it will write m calls to DoWork() and n calls to DoWork().

```
template<typename TypeBasedOnMonth>
DoWork(TypeBasedOnWeekday weekday) 
{
   switch (weekday)
   {
    case Weekday1:
        DoWork<TypeBasedOnMonth, TypeWeekday1>();
        break;
    case Weekday2:
        DoWork<TypeBasedOnMonth, TypeWeekday2>();
        ...
   }
   ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
    switch (month)
    {
    case Month1:
        DoWork<TypeMonth1>(weekday);
        break;
    case Month2:
        DoWork<TypeMonth2>(weekday);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```